# What algorithm to use to exchange data between multiple parties

Tags: security, encryption, hash, cryptography

Let's say there are Alice, Bob, Eve and Arbitrator.

And let's say

Alice has a table of records

```
|      id | pet type | birth date |
|----------------------------------
|       1 |      cat | 2010-03-03 |
|       2 |      dog | 2011-06-12 |
```

Bob has a table of records

```
|      id | pet type |    color |
|-------------------------------|
|       2 |      dog |    white |
|       3 |     bird |    green |
```

Eve has a table of records

```
|      id | pet type |     size |
|--------------------------------
|       1 |      cat |    small |
|       3 |     bird |    small |
```

Now everyone wants to enrich his own data by the neighbor's data with the corresponding id, but without disclosuring this id, for example,

Alice wants her data to be like the following

```
|      id | pet type | birth date |   color |    size |
|------------------------------------------------------
|       1 |      cat | 2010-03-03 |         |   small |
|       2 |      dog | 2011-06-12 |   white |         |
```

Bob wants his data to be like the following

```
|      id | pet type | birth date |   color |    size |
|------------------------------------------------------
|       2 |      dog | 2011-06-12 |   white |         |
|       3 |     bird |            |   green |   small |
```

and so on.

Arbitrator coordinates all the exchange operations between the parties and also matches the data using corresponding encrypted id fields from the dataset of each party, so parties must communicate through the arbitrator, but not directly to each other.

Also arbitrator must be able to ensure that

`hash(Alice's id = 2) = hash(Bob's id = 2), hash(Bob's id = 3) = hash(Eve's id = 3)`

and so on, but must not be able to recover original identifiers, and also arbitrator must not be able to brute-force the encrypted identifiers (so if talking about some kind of hashes - they must be salted)

To simplify things for Alice, Bob and Eve - they would like to have only a single key to encrypt own identifiers, but this key should be different for each party, i.e.

`F1(alive_key(alice_id)) = F2(bob_key(bob_id)) = F3(eve_key(eve_id))`

where, F1, F2, F3 - are some functions the arbitrator applies to encrypted identifiers of Alice, Bob and Eve, and these functions does not decrypt the original identifiers, but lead the encrypted identifiers to be the same.

So the question - is there any algorithm that can help to solve such an issue?

Comment: Eve is generally consider to be the evil attacker, don't trust her. ;-)

Comment: Alice wants to forget about id 2?

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson, updated a little bit a description. Alice doesn't want to forget id 2. She wants to join her table with others tables without sharing original values of id to arbitrator.